# rails server works but "rails console" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails project. With command "bundle exec rails s" I can fire up a local server, however, "bundle exec rails c" throws the following errors:

```
 /Users/wh026399/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/wh026399/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/wh026399/healthelife_web/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
    from /Users/wh026399/healthelife_web/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/wh026399/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/wh026399/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/wh026399/healthelife_web/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:77:in `preload'
    from /Users/wh026399/healthelife_web/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/wh026399/healthelife_web/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/wh026399/healthelife_web/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/wh026399/healthelife_web/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/wh026399/healthelife_web/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/wh026399/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/wh026399/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

- Ruby version: 2.2.2
- Rails version: 4.2.5
- gem version: 2.5.2
- Bundler version: 1.11.2

[UPDATE]: it turns out that commenting out "spring" in Gemfile will solve this issue.

Comment: Also, I didn't install ruby 2.2.0, why it's showing up in the path?

Comment: forgot to mention, I have a .bundle/config file that sets BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle so gems are installed under vendor/bundle in my project directory instead of system wide.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I came across this after having the same problem as poster. His update suggesting that removing spring from the Gemfile helped me get on the right track. The problem for me was that I had introduced a new environment variables, but spring didn't pick it up. When you remove spring from the Gemfile, it prevents your app from using the spring process, *but it doesn't actually stop the spring process so adding it back, doing bundle install, or anything else will still leave you with the same spring process running.*

To see if this is likely your issue, you can check `bin/spring status` and see if spring is running in the background, and if it has been running for a while.

Solution (at least for me): restart spring

```
bin/spring stop
rails c
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `gem update --system`? You may need an updated version of rubygems.

Comment: yes, I tried and it bumps gem's version to 2.5.2, but still see the error.

Comment: @user1783403 do `[sudo] gem install bundler`
and then `bundle install`

Comment: Just trying to help. 1) what about switching back to your system ruby. `rvm use system`. 2) i see your error message related to spring, so maybe you can try `gem install spring`

Comment: I suspect the path is wrong. In my gem env, INSTALLATION DIRECTORY is /Users/wh026399/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2 but USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY is /Users/wh026399/.gem/ruby/2.2.0 where does ruby 2.2.0 come from? I only installed 2.2.2 and 2.0.0

Comment: In your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, is it pointing to the ruby version where bundler is installed?

Comment: I don't even have an nginx folder under /etc

Answer (score 0):

if you use rvm set the default ruby version using following, so it will pickup the correct ruby version. you probably needs to run bundle install/gem install rails -v 4.2.5 after setting the default

```
rvm --default 2.2.2
```

Comment: 2.2.2 is my current default and I did rerun bundle install after that, still no luck :(